# Where to place my external database for my android app on the internet for free

Tags: android, database, web-services, wamp

I have made an Android app that has an external database, using WAMP and MySQL.
In my app, the users will have to first register or login into my app to use it.

Right now I have this external database running locally on my laptop, but at the time when I will publish my app I should place that external DB on the internet.

So where is the best place to place my external DB on the internet for free, where my app users can get connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many free mysql hosting sites out there, www.000webhost.com and www.host1free.com I have tried. They limit you to the amount of databases but should do the trick for free too as requested. Just register and set up your databases as needed and upload the correct server scripts then add the address to your android app. Good luck :)

Comment: Thankyou so much. I had no idea where to put my db on the internet. Your post helped alot.
I just wanted to know that I can I just upload my existing db on theses webhosting sites.
And one more thing how can I know how many users are interacting with my app like analytics?
Thanks once again!  :)

Comment: your welcome anytime, I plan to do the same as you. Not sure about analytics but you can see some information from your market account dashboard of active installs likewise reviews etc

Comment: ThankYou so much. Yeah you are right I can view it from market reviews.
Thanks! You are a great help!

Comment: Anytime man :) no problem, I think the statistics found on the dashboard should be sufficient.